# Vandalism from these 2 accounts

Tags: support, spam

There are several posts from these 2 accounts - https://superuser.com/users/238676/doland and https://superuser.com/users/238678/tyrone, in this question:

[How to retrieve data from Firefox sync account?](https://superuser.com/questions/620769/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firefox-sync-account/620797#620797)

I've flagged them, is there anything more I could do?

What should be done in general when dealing with these problems? I've never encountered anything like that in StackOverflow, does this happen often on SuperUser?

I learned about them because they also posted on my own question:

[Why is deleting files to recycle bin so much slower than when using Shift+Del with Total Commander?](https://superuser.com/questions/620813/why-is-deleting-files-to-recycle-bin-so-much-slower-than-when-using-shiftdel-wi)

Comment: Now that it's deleted, that's actually... pretty darned funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We haven't seen too much of those, looks like bunch of bloke/s too bored/drunk for anything.

Next time, just flag for spam/offensive instead of " it needs ♦ moderator attention" -

[image]

6 flags of type spam/offensive will automatically nuke the post. [You could drop by chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) & ask regulars in chat to pitch in their spam flags.

Comment: I wondered whether I should flag them as such, but their posts weren't advertisements, just vandalism. So should we flag vandalism as spam, even if it's not advertising?

Comment: @satuon you can always select the offensive one, aka "it is not welcome in our community" - that carries the 6-flag-penalty as well